# Stop movieclip from scaling in AS3 projector

Tags: flash

How can I allow some elements to scale and not allow some elements to scale when playing the projector in fullscreen mode.

I've an application where I need the flvplayback component not to scale along with the stage because the videos get pixelated in higher resolution monitors.

How can I achieve this. Noscale property works for the whole stage, but I need few elements to be exempted from scaling

Answer (score 0):

What I think you can do is add an event listener for going full screen. If not just some way to check when it has happened. When this happens run a function that just scales down whatever you want back to its original size. This effectively makes it not get scaled. Hope this helps.